# interaction term interpretation

Tags: regression, categorical-data, interpretation

I have the following regression:

```
 y = -0.006396 + -0.029852*x1 + 0.003384*x2 +0.024112*x1*x2
```

each x1 and x2 are dummy variables each with two categories 0 and 1.

I have coefficients' signs as -0.029852 > 0, 0.003384 < 0, and 0.024112 > 0

But only the coefficient for x2 is insignificant.

When I look into the raw data, I find no case when x1*x2 > 0

If so, can I still safely interpret as the coefficient of x1*x2  > 0 although I do not find the exact case in my raw data?

Comment: Before you go further, what are the p-values for your coefficients? Recall, you shouldn't discuss coefficients which are not significant. 

What if there are nonlinearities in the original data that were recoded to dummy variables?  

By not showing the computer output, it's impossible to support what you are observing.

Comment: I used real numbers as requested. Please check above. Only one coefficient for x2 is insignificant.

Comment: Have a look at the picture on my post [here](https://stats.stackexchange.com/a/276686/21054). It illustrates how to interptret interaction terms between dummy variables. As a side note: I recommend looking at some residual diagnostic plots before interpreting the coefficients and confidence intervals and p-values.

Comment: @COOLSerdash: That was a great help. Thank you so much. But will looking at the residual diagnostic plots change the interpretation especially in my case? According to your logic, I safely find that the combined interaction effect of x1 and x2 is a negative value.

Comment: So since the binary variable is only between 0 and 1, it seems like I can safely assume that my interaction effect between x1 and x2 is negative since neither x1 nor x2 cannot have values greater than one. May I confirm whether this is correct?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The signs of the variables are completely irrelevant.  The interaction term is negative.  Your regression equation is

> y = -0.006396 + -0.029852*x1 + 0.003384*x2 +0.024112*x1*x2

This just gives you the predicted value of y for every combination of x's.  Since they are both dummy variables, you have only 4 combinations.

- x1 = 0, x2 = 0, predicted y = -0.006
- x1 = 0, x2 = 1, predicted y = -0.006 - 0.030 = -0.036
- x1 = 1, x2 = 0, predicted y = -0.006 + 0.003 = -0.003
- x1 = 1, x2 = 1, predicted y = -0.006  - 0.030 + 0.003 + 0.024 = -0.001

Comment: Thank you so much for your confirmation that the answer is negative. The detailed explanation helped me a lot.