# interpreting coefficients of interaction terms between categorical variables

Tags: regression, self-study, interaction, categorical-encoding

Assuming I have a linear regression model of the form:

Y = a + (b1*fact1) + (b2*fact2) + b3*(fact1*fact2) + b4*other_var

where, fact1, fact2 are categorical variables of 2 factors each, YES and NO
and other_var is a continuous variable and in the regression model, b3 represents the coefficient when both fact1=fact2=YES

a) is the intercept a, the effect on response Y in the case where both fact1 and fact2 are 0?

b) is the effect on the response Y when fact1=fact2=YES, given by b1+b2+b3?

c) is the effect on the response Y when fact1=YES, fact2=NO, given just by b1?

Model structure as shown in the picture for easier reference:
[image]

Comment: If this is related to a school/college assignment, please add the `self-study` tag, and show us what you've been able to do, so we know you at least tried solving the problem.

Comment: the question is based on a regression output that I worked on for an assignment with a lot more variables; showing what I worked on/the output would mean taking a screenshot of the output. I'm just trying to understand if my inference is right, especially with regards to the intercept

Comment: @LucasFarias He came up with the right answer himself, and it is posted on the question, so it is hard to believe that he did not try

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Does it make sense to interact 2 dummy variables?](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/276668/does-it-make-sense-to-interact-2-dummy-variables)

Answer (score 0):

You are absolutelly right, it is exactly as you posted it (assuming other_var is equal to 0, otherwise you will have to add $b_4 * othervar$)