# How do I code interaction terms when I have dummy variables?

Tags: regression, machine-learning, logistic

I have a dataset from an AB test. It shows the conversion rate per treatment group and the categories within each variant.

```
category     group         converted
green        control       0
green        control       0
green        control       1
blue         control       1
blue         control       0
purple       control       1 
purple       control       1 
yellow       control       1
yellow       control       0
green        treatment     0 
green        treatment     0 
blue         treatment     0
blue         treatment     1
purple       treatment     1
purple       treatment     1
yellow       treatment     0
yellow       treatment     1
```

I'm putting together a logistic regression to predict the likelihood of conversion as a function of the category + the group. I have about 10K records altogether.

I am encoding the category as is_green (0/1), is_blue (0/1), is_yellow(0/1) and is_purple(0/1). I am encoding the group as group(0/1).

I would like to see the group, but it also looks like there may be some interaction effect going on.

How do I capture the interaction in the logistic model when both variables are encoded?

Answer (score 1):

You can multiply them, just like you would in other models, like linear ones.

Say you have dummy variables $v_1$ and $v_2$, both assuming either $0$ or $1$, and you want to capture their interaction. For this you could create $w=v_1 v_2$ to asses the effect they'd have when the events they represent happen together.

Naturally, you can also include, separately, $v_1$ and $v_2$ and asses their individual effects.

[This answer](https://stats.stackexchange.com/a/276686/127281) has a much in-depth example of how to interpret the results.