# Interpretation of coefficients in a linear regression model with two binary predictors and their interaction

Tags: r, multiple-regression, linear-model, interaction, lm

This is the output from a linear regression model that is trying to predict math scores based on the student's gender and whether or not they took a test preparation course. It is just a toy example for me to understand how to interpret the coefficients.

```
> str(StudentsPerformance)
'data.frame':   1000 obs. of  8 variables:
 $ gender                     : chr  "female" "female" "female" "male" ...
 $ test.preparation.course    : chr  "none" "completed" "none" "none" ...
 $ math.score                 : int  72 69 90 47 76 71 88 40 64 38 ...
```

The model includes an interaction term between gender and test preparation course.

lm(formula = math.score ~ 1 + gender * test.preparation.course,
data = StudentsPerformance)

```
Residuals:
    Min      1Q  Median      3Q     Max 
-61.671  -9.671   0.329   9.804  38.329 

Coefficients:
                                       Estimate Std. Error t value Pr(>|t|)    
(Intercept)                             67.1957     1.0857  61.889  < 2e-16 ***
gendermale                               5.1434     1.5574   3.303 0.000992 ***
test.preparation.coursenone             -5.5250     1.3521  -4.086 4.74e-05 ***
gendermale:test.preparation.coursenone   3.1258     1.9440  -0.065 0.050426 .
```

I made the following statements :

- the intercept is the average math score for female students who completed the test preparation course
- males have a math score that is 5.1434 points higher than females between those who completed the course
- females who didn't take a test preparation course have a math score that is 5.5250 points lower than females who took the course
- the effect of a test preparation course is different for male and females. Male students who did not take the test preparation course have a math score 3.1258 points higher than female students who took the test preparation course

is that a correct interpretation?

Answer (score 1):

Personally, I like to draw a table for these kinds of situations (see [this post](https://stats.stackexchange.com/a/276686/21054)). Your model is:

$$
\operatorname{E}(\mathrm{mathscore}|\mathrm{gender}, \mathrm{course}) = \beta_{0} + \beta_{1}\mathrm{gender_{m}} + \beta_{2}\mathrm{course_{none}} + \beta_{3}\underbrace{\mathrm{gender_{m}}\times\mathrm{course_{none}}}_{\text{= interaction term}}
$$

Tabulating all possible combinations with their corresponding coefficients, we have:

$$
\begin{array}{l|l|l}
 & \text{Gender = m} & \text{Gender= f} & \text{Difference} \\
\hline
\text{Course = completed} & \beta_{0} + \beta_{1} & \beta_{0} & \beta_{1} \\
\text{Course = none} & \beta_{0} + \beta_{1} + \beta_{2} + \beta_{3} & \beta_{0} + \beta_{2} & \beta_{1} + \beta_{3} \\ \hline
\text{Difference} & \beta_{2} + \beta_{3} & \beta_{2}  & \beta_{3} 
\end{array}
$$

Let's summarize the interpretation:

- $\beta_{0}$ is the estimated average math score for a female with a completed course.
- $\beta_{1}$ is the difference between males and females that completed the course.
- $\beta_{2}$ is the difference between females who completed the course and those who didn't.
- $\beta_{3}$ is the *additional* difference between the average math scores between males and females when we change from course completed to none. To make it specific: The difference between males and females who did complete the course is $\beta_{1} = 5.14$ but the difference between males and females who did not complete the course is $\beta_{1} + \beta_{3} = 5.14 + 3.13 = 8.27$.

Here is a schematic plot that hopefully aids the interpretation (note that the depicted effects do not correspond to the values of your coefficient):

[image: Interactionplot]

Comment: How can I generalize these results, say that I wanted to know if males have a math score higher than females between those who completed the course and those who not completed?

Comment: I'm unsure what you mean by generalize? The difference between males and females among the completers is $\beta_{1}$ whereas it is $\beta_{1} + \beta_{3}$ among non-completers. Therefore, the difference of the differences (m vs f) is $\beta_{3}$.